# Plant/Residue Detection project, How to structure it?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

**Introduction**

I have wanted to develop this project for more than two years. I just started writing it a couple days ago. I use it to detect plant or residue pixels in crop row images but it provides a good example of how to detect green and red color. I could not find anything like this on Stackoverflow/Stackexchange, but I did end up finding some information on the IEEE site. I think this will benefit someone that came after me.

**Core Concept**

The core concept is really easy.
Assume that your crop row images are in this [dataset](http://www.etfos.unios.hr/r3dvgroup/index.php?id=crd_dataset).

To detect a Plant (color green), convert the RGB image to a gray scale image using the formula:

```
GRAY = 2*G-R-B
```

To detect Residue (color red), convert the RGB image to a gray scale image using the formula:

```
GRAY = 1.5*R-G-B
```

Basically, if you want to apply theses algorithm/equation above for something else, you should change the constants 1.5 and 2 to fit your task.

**Project**

So I decided to publish this [repository](https://github.com/pacozaa/plantdetector).
There are three main scripts:

1. `index.py` analyzes all images in the "images" folder.
2. `webcamplant.py` analyzes images directly from a camera streaming images in real time.
3. `covEX.py` contains the actual algorithm. It is written using `numpy` (check out my previous question for more information).

**index.py**

```
import covEX
import time
import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

start_time = time.time()
pathname = 'Images/'
pathsave = 'Images-converted/'

filelist = [f for f in listdir(pathname) if isfile(join(pathname, f))]

for i, val in enumerate(filelist):
    print('processing file number '+str(i))
    filename = os.path.splitext(val)[0]
    fileextension = os.path.splitext(val)[1]
    covEX.convertTofile(pathname, filename, fileextension, pathsave)

print('Shite! I\'m done ;) ')
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

**webcamplant.py**

```
import covEX
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Our operations on the frame come here    
    plantimg = covEX.convertGreenSerious(frame)
    # Display the resulting frame
    plantimg = cv2.flip(plantimg,1)
    cv2.imshow('frame',plantimg)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**covEX.py**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os


def calEXG(red,green,blue):
    result = 2*green-red-blue
    return result

def calEXR(red,green,blue):
    result = 1.5*red-green-blue
    return result

def savePlants(savename,plantimg,exgimg,exgimgblurred,original,notblurred,blurred,otsu,extension):
    cv2.imwrite(savename+'/'+original+extension,plantimg)
    cv2.imwrite(savename+'/'+notblurred+extension,exgimg)
    cv2.imwrite(savename+'/'+blurred+extension,exgimgblurred)

    # ret2,th2 = cv2.threshold(exgimgblurred,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    # cv2.imwrite(savename+'/'+otsu+extension,th2)


def convertGreenSerious(rawimg):
    blue = rawimg[:,:,0]
    green = rawimg[:,:,1]
    red = rawimg[:,:,2]
    exg = 1.5*green-red-blue
    processedimg = np.where(exg > 50, exg, 0)
    processedimg = np.uint8(np.abs(processedimg))

    return processedimg

def convertGreenPlant(rawimg):
    blue = rawimg[:,:,0]
    green = rawimg[:,:,1]
    red = rawimg[:,:,2]
    exg = 2*green-red-blue
    processedimg = np.where(exg > 50, exg, 0)
    processedimg = np.uint8(np.abs(processedimg))

    return processedimg

def convertRed(rawimg):
    blue = rawimg[:,:,0]
    green = rawimg[:,:,1]
    red = rawimg[:,:,2]
    exg = 1.5*red-green-blue
    processedimg = np.where(exg > 50, exg, 0)

    return processedimg



def convertTofile(filepath,filename,extension,savepath):
    directory = filepath+filename+extension
    plantimg = cv2.imread(directory)

    exgimg = convertGreenPlant(plantimg)
    exgimgblurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(exgimg,(5,5),0)

    if not os.path.exists(savepath+filename):
        os.makedirs(savepath+filename)

    savePlants(savepath+filename,plantimg,exgimg,exgimgblurred,'original','notblurred','blurred','otsu','.png')
```

How should I improve this project to be more professional and easy to integrate with other peoples projects?

PS. Some good reads for this research topic:

- [Color Indices for Weed Identification Under Various Soil, Residue, and Lighting Conditions](http://elibrary.asabe.org/abstract.asp?aid=27838)
- [A vision based row detection system for sugar beet](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168169907001615)
- [A machine vision based crop rows detection for agricultural robots](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5576422/)
- [The research of image segmentation based on color characteristic](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6016969/)
- [An efficient crop row detection method for agriculture robots](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=7003860)
- [Multi-crop-row detection based on strip analysis](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7009678/)
- [Vision-Based Row Detection Algorithms Evaluation for Weeding Cultivator Guidance in Lentil](http://www.ccsenet.org/journal/index.php/mas/article/view/35547)

Comment: To my mind the canonical source on this is http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/08/16/open-sourcing-a-python-project-the-right-way/